# Como organizar meu projeto?

Tags: react

Estou começando a aprender `react` native e estou com bastante dúvidas sobre como estruturar meu projeto. Estou criando um jogo da velha, que tem a seguinte configuração:

[image: Component's Structure]
[image: Tree Representation]

Como vocês podem ver, cada um dos componentes reside em seu próprio arquivo js.

Estou pensando onde é o melhor lugar para colocar a lógica do jogo, quero dizer, vamos supor que eu tenho uma matriz 3x3 como um atributo do meu componente raiz (assumindo que a estrutura do componente é uma árvore) e as folhas são os espaços vazios onde podemos marcar 'X' ou 'O'.

Como se da a comunicação das folhas para a raiz? Por exemplo, clicando em um espaço vazio, invoco um método `putMarkOn (row, col)`, que estaria na classe jogo, por exemplo.

A imagem mostra a estrutura dos componentes, o que eu quero saber é ... onde inserir a lógica, talvez em um arquivo externo chamado GameLogic?

E como atualizar o estado do jogo, de acordo com a interação de toque?

Comment: Nada galera? nenhuma resposta? De qualquer forma obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro o React em si é uma um biblioteca que prove a camada **V** do dito **MVC**. A View basicamente é composta por componentes.

Existem componentes *dummy*, como os que você possui (TitleBox, ContentBox, Row, Col e etc...), e componentes de negócio. Esse ultimo é composto por elementos *dummy*, e regras de negócio.

No seu caso você tem o **TouchBox**, você pode separa-lo em dois componentes. Primeiro um *dummy* que só prove a renderização e um outro componente de negócio que contem o componente de renderização e também a regra de negócio.

```
export default class ComponenteNegocio extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    /*
        Aqui vai a regra de negócio
    */

    render() {
        return (
            <Dummy { ...this.props }></ Dummy>
        )
    }
}
```

Lembrando que você pode ter vários componentes de negócio em uma mesma aplicação, sempre que usar esse tipo de componente você renderiza o mesmo quando quiser um componente com regras e renderiza o *dummy* quando quiser somente mostrar algo sem a regra de negócio. O ideal é criar duas pastas na raiz do projeto um com componentes *dummy* e outra com os de negócio

Comment: Desculpa o Atraso rsrsr e realmente obrigado :)